# Fitting UIPicker and 3 text fields on 3.5 and 4 inch devices

Tags: xcode, swift, autolayout, uipickerview

I have (from top to bottom) 2 UILabels, 1 UIPickerView, 3 UITexfield, and 1 button.  Given the size of the picker, upon the keyboard appearing it overlaps my text fields on the 3.5 and 4 inch devices.  I used some code to pop the text fields up when the keyboard shows, but I'm unsure what to do with the picker.  I tried hiding it upon keyboard but it's too sudden and the user may want to change their choice which they can't easily.  What should I do with the picker given the size limitations?

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        countyPicker.delegate = self
        countyPicker.dataSource = self


            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);
        }

        func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= 150
        }

        func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
            self.view.frame.origin.y += 150
  //          countyPicker.hidden = true

    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return titleData.mdCounties.count
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent componefnt: Int) {
 //       countyPicker.alpha = 0.3
        selectedCounty = titleData.mdCounties[row].name
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {

        return titleData.mdCounties[row].name!
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the 1 UIPickerView and 3 UITexfield in a single view and pop up the entire view when the keyboard shows up.

As you have already written the code to pop up the text fields it will work out.

Hope this helps you. :)

Comment: Thanks I added a hidden view, but I'm not sure:  how do I group those UI elements inside my view and then pop it up?

Comment: Add a UIView in the place of the UIPickerView and UITextfield. Now drag those UI elements into the view you have added newly. And then animate the entire view while the keyboard is appearing.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a simple line indicating the selection of the picker. When the line is tapped, you can show or hide the picker below the line with animation.

It would probably make sense to do this in a `UITableView`. Look at how Apple shows and hides date pickers in its Calendar app when you edit an event. You can do this very beautifully with standard row animations when inserting and deleting table view rows.

The table view solution is also more flexible as it will always work, even if in the future the number of items that have to be displayed would increase or if Apple introduces the new iPhone nano.